# LG G2 - USB debugging disables when I connect to a PC

Tags: usb-debugging, lg-g2

I'm trying to set up remote debugging on my brand new LG G2 phone.

Seen here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/mobile/

So far, I've:

1. Enabled developer options
2. Enabled "USB debugging" on the Developer options screen
3. On the "PC Connections" screen - I've set "USB connection method" to "PC Software"

So - everything looks good at this point.

However, as soon as I connect the device to my PC, the "USB debugging" setting on the "Developer options" screen turns gray (disabled). If I go to DevTools on Chrome on my PC (chrome://inspect/#devices) and check "Discover USB devices", my phone is not listed.

What else do I need to do?

Comment: Installed the correct drivers (Windows) / adjusted the configuration of your computer (Linux/Mac) accordingly? Without that, your computer will not be able to recognize the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with my G2 D802 only mine did work before when still running android 4.2.
It was a driver issue and fixed it by the folowing steps:

- download the Android SDK at : http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
- unzip the package and run the file : SDK Manager.exe
- Scroll down to extra's and check google USB driver and install packages
  http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html#top for a little more info

My usb setting is set at (MTP)

That did it for me.

Answer (score 4):

The PC Software setting is just for installing and using the LG PC software. Once your drivers are installed, enable USB Debugging, plug it in, change it from "charge only" to "MTP" and USB Debugging should work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I followed all the steps in this video to install the drivers: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ltd2bfCpMB4. However - as soon as I connect the device, the "USB debugging" option within the "Developer options" screen (which is checked) grays out. (It's not gray before I connect). In other words - it's as though connecting the device causes the option to disable. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you change the connection mode to MTP? "Charge Only" & "PC Software" will disable USB Debugging.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.

Comment: Had the same issue with LG G5... I had to install the CORRECT original drivers and afterwards be sure to use MTP connection (Media Transfer Protocol). Only after reading this answer I got the second point.

Comment: Look for "LG united mobile driver" on google and install those drivers, then with the usual procedure you should manage to connect