# USB debugging doesn't work - switches off automatically

Tags: usb-debugging

I have a Xolo Q800 phone with following specs. I'm trying to connect the device to my Macbook Pro with OS X Mavericks, Android Studio / Eclipse and adb working perfectly.

XOLO Q800
Android 4.2.1 (Upgraded, device came with 4.1.2)
Rooted
Mediatek MT6589M Chipset
Quad-core 1.2 GHz Processor
1GB RAM

Recently I noticed I'm not able to connect this device to any machine as USB Debugging will switch off automatically almost immediately.

Settings > Development > USB Debugging.
After I switch it on, the device reconnects to the computer but is not detected by adb.
On device go back one menu and again in Development, I see USB Debugging as disabled.

It used to work perfectly before as I have used this device earlier for development.
Not sure if the update to 4.2.1 broke it as I do not remember any issues after it.

Can anyone please give some pointers here? The manufacturer support is pretty non existing in this matter.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/63444/53576 this may help

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, if you follow these steps you should be able to see your device.

1. Install SAMSUNG USB Driver v1.5.33.0 from [here](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/SW/201401/20140121132354500/SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones_v1.5.33.0.exe).
2. Restart your PC.
3. Connect qolo q800 and enable USB debugging.
4. Go to device manager and click on update software
5. Choose browse my computer for software. Then choose 'let me pick'
6. Choose adb interface

Thats it. Open eclipse and make your minimum SDK is 4.2.1(API level 16) or below.